# Coding Multiple Models in a Function in R Tidyverse

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I am trying to fit a couple of machine learning models with a few formulas and store them in a tibble as list_column objects.

I have tried to modify the code quoted in book 'R for Datascience' (Chapter 25 : Many Models) but it only gives me the last output. Please refer to below code for more details. We are using the gapminder dataset from the gapminder packages as an example.

```
lab_formula <- as.formula("pop ~ lifeExp ")

temp_formula <- as.formula("gdppercap ~ year")

formula_list <- list(lab_formula,temp_formula)
library(gapminder)

by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  dplyr :: group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  nest()

country_model <- function(df) {
for (i in formula_list) {
  lm(formula=formula[i], data = df)
  randomForest(formula=formula[i], data = df)
  gbm(formula=formula[i], data = df, n.minobsinnode = 2)
}
}

by_country <- by_country %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, country_model))

by_country
# A tibble: 142 x 4
   country     continent data              model    
   <fct>       <fct>     <list>            <list>   
 1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 7 Austria     Europe    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 8 Bahrain     Asia      <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
 9 Bangladesh  Asia      <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
10 Belgium     Europe    <tibble [12 x 4]> <S3: gbm>
# ... with 132 more rows

There is no error code but it does not achieve my objective of training the 3 machine learning models (LM, RF, GBM) with the different variables.
```

Comment: Your function `country_model` doesn't output anything. You should create an object and pass it through `return`. Also, you didn't store your models in an object as they were created, so what would you output anyway? Your models probably did run, but you didn't get any output because you didn't assign them to an object and then return that from the function.

Comment: Hi Dij, the variable 'by_country' will output my model result. Please see edited question to make it clearer.

Comment: I think you're overwriting every model in your function call so that you just end up with the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about how you want to store your results. Here is one way to do that. First create a list of formulas you want to apply

```
library(randomForest)
library(gbm)
library(tidyverse)

lab_formula <- as.formula("pop ~ lifeExp ")
temp_formula <- as.formula("gdpPercap ~ year")
formula_list <- list(lab_formula,temp_formula)
```

Create a function which returns a list of models applied only to one formula at a time.

```
country_model <- function(df, formula_list, index) {
    list(lm(formula = formula_list[[index]] , data = df), 
         randomForest(formula=formula_list[[index]], data = df),
         gbm(formula=formula_list[[index]], data = df, n.minobsinnode = 2))
}
```

and now apply it to each `data` passing the `formula_list` and formula number from the list that you want to apply to your data,

```
df1 <- by_country %>% 
  mutate(model1 = map(data, ~country_model(., formula_list, 1)), 
         model2 = map(data, ~country_model(., formula_list, 2)))
df1

# A tibble: 142 x 5
#   country     continent data              model1     model2    
#   <fct>       <fct>     <list>            <list>     <list>    
# 1 Afghanistan Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 2 Albania     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 3 Algeria     Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 4 Angola      Africa    <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 5 Argentina   Americas  <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 6 Australia   Oceania   <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 7 Austria     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 8 Bahrain     Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# 9 Bangladesh  Asia      <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
#10 Belgium     Europe    <tibble [12 × 4]> <list [3]> <list [3]>
# … with 132 more rows
```

Now every row in `model1` has a list of three models which used the formula `formula_list[[1]]` and similarly for `model2` you have models which used formula `formula_list[[2]]`.

---

To use these models for prediction we can need to treat randomForest model differently since it needs `n.trees` parameter and as we return those models from our function we know it is the third model in the list we can distinguish it based on the index.

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(pred= map2(data,model1, function(x, y) 
     map(seq_along(y), function(i) 
        if (i == 3) predict(y[[i]], n.trees = y[[i]]$n.trees)
        else as.numeric(predict(y[[i]])))))
```

Comment: I have an add-on question and hope you guys can help! Are we able to use the 'invoke_map' function to apply on the above machine learning models?

Basically, ```models_tbl_fit <- models_tbl %>%
    mutate(fit = invoke_map(f, params))
models_tbl_fit```

Please refer to the weblink below for further details:
https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/sweep/vignettes/SW02_Forecasting_Multiple_Models.html

Comment: @MatthewLoh I haven't used `invoke_map` before but reading the documentation it says it has been [retired](https://www.tidyverse.org/lifecycle/#retired) and is not under active development and there are better alternatives to it.

Comment: Thank you so much again! Last last question!
Is the code for doing predictions as follows:
```by_country <- by_country %>% mutate(pred=map2(data,model1,add_predictions))```

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "n.trees" is missing, with no default.

But i got an error because randomforest predictions requires an additional argument. How do i insert that in>

Comment: @MatthewLoh Does `add_predictions` have `n.trees` argument? If not then you may need to use `stats::predict` separately for randomForest which can accept that argument. `predict(model,  n.trees = model$n.trees)`

Comment: The ```add_predictions``` does not have a ```n.trees argument```. However, the documentation states that we can change the prediction type to use the ```stats::predict```. However, how does that translate to the R code?

I get this error when I tried the code you provided :
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Index 1 must have length 1.

So how do we discriminate the random forest model from the normal LM and GBM models?

Comment: @MatthewLoh Updated the answer, should be solvable now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195560/discussion-between-matthew-loh-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: Sorry, but could we use a for loop with the code below to generate multiple new columns which are predictions of all the different model formulas (model1,model2,model3?
```
df1 %>%
   mutate(pred= map2(data,model1, function(x, y) 
     map(seq_along(y), function(i) 
        if (i == 3) predict(y[[i]], n.trees = y[[i]]$n.trees)
        else as.numeric(predict(y[[i]])))))
```

Comment: @MatthewLoh I would suggest you to ask a new question with updated information because the original question was about adding multiple models which was answered. Usually every post should solve only one particular problem.